# Detecting input collision on overlapping 2D objects in Unity

Tags: c#, input, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an app that has many balls that float around but do not collide with each other. This means they overlap a lot. I've got it so if you click/touch the balls, they are destroyed. However, if one ball is behind another, this one is not destroyed until the one in front is cleared.

[image]

The above diagram shows what I'm looking for, if the user clicks/touches at position x, then destroy all the objects, not just the most forward of them. Any help much appreciated.

Here's my input script:

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TouchInput : MonoBehaviour {

    public LayerMask touchInputMask;
    private List<GameObject> touchList = new List<GameObject> ();
    private GameObject[] touchesOld;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;

    void Update () {


#if UNITY_EDITOR

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

            touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
            touchList.CopyTo (touchesOld);
            touchList.Clear ();


            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, touchInputMask);
            //Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            if (hit) {

                GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                touchList.Add (recipient);

                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                    recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchDown",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                }
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
                    recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchUp",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                }
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                    recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchStay",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                }

            }

            foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld) {
                if (!touchList.Contains (g)) {
                    if(g!=null) {
                        g.SendMessage ("OnTouchExit", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                    }

                }
            }

        }

#endif

        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

            touchesOld = new GameObject[touchList.Count];
            touchList.CopyTo (touchesOld);
            touchList.Clear ();

            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {

                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, touchInputMask);

                if (hit) {

                    GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                    touchList.Add (recipient);

                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
                        recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchDown",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                    }
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
                        recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchUp",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                    }
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
                        recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchStay",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                    }
                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) {
                        recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchExit",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                    }

                }

            }

            foreach (GameObject g in touchesOld) {
                if (!touchList.Contains (g)) {
                    if (g != null) {
                        g.SendMessage ("OnTouchExit", hit.point, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And on the ball I simply have a:

```
    void OnTouchDown() {

    KillBall ();
}

void OnTouchStay() {

    KillBall ();

}
```

Comment: Are all balls on same z position?

Comment: If you are wanting to remove all balls underneath the finger/mouse then use RaycastAll instead of Raycast - http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html you should be able to loop through all of the returned RaycastHit2D's and Destroy their gameobjects.

Comment: Yeah all the balls are on the same z, I'll check out the RaycastAll..

Comment: Your solution is the comment above with RaycastAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by @Savlon, so thanks for that :)

```
private RaycastHit2D[] hits;
```

...

```
hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero, touchInputMask);

        foreach(RaycastHit2D hit in hits) {

            GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
            touchList.Add (recipient);

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchDown",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
                recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouchUp",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                recipient.SendMessage ("OnTouch",hit.point,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

            }


        }
```